# terraform failing at google subscription creation (contradicting its own documentation)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have the following terraform code:

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "push_subscriptions" {
  name                       = var.subscription_name
  topic                      = var.topic_name
  project                    = var.project_id
  push_config {
    push_endpoint = var.push_endpoint
    oidc_token {
      service_account_email = var.sa_email
    }
  }
}
```

As per [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/pubsub_subscription.html) "oidc_token" comes under "resource.push_config".

But I don't know why I am getting this error:

> (base) [(01:10:36) sw@Stunners-MAC terraform-tests]$
> terraform plan
>
> Error: Unsupported block type
>
> on sub.tf line 7, in resource "google_pubsub_subscription"
> "push_subscriptions":    7:     oidc_token {
>
> Blocks of type "oidc_token" are not expected here.

Comment: Is it a version issue? Does your terraform up to date?

Comment: I have tried with both 0.11 and 0.12. Its failing with both

Comment: Can you try with 0.13? In any case, it should work with 0.12

Comment: In this particular case, it's more relevant which version of the Google Cloud Platform provider you are running, not which version of Terraform you are running. It's the provider that defines what arguments are expected for each resource type it offers.

Comment: If you view [the docs in the Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs), rather than the snapshot of the latest presented on `terraform.io`, you can select the specific provider version you are using and see how that particular version is documented.